# React-router match string after last dash before slash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've encountered a super weird issue, which I can't seem to resolve. I have such a react-router route as a redirect:

`/something/(.*-)?:id/:view?`

And when I try to match such URL: `/something/slug-of-title-106/Steps/123,233` matching works as intended. I get correct match params like that:

```
"params": {
  "0": "slug-of-title-",
  "id": "106",
  "view": "Steps"
}
```

Now, I keep thing called "steps" in my URL and `-2` is the indicator of last "step". And when I have URL like this: `/explanation/slug-of-title-106/Steps/123,231,-2` everything crashes down and my match results in this:

```
"params": {
  "0": "slug-of-title-106/Steps/123,231,-",
  "id": "2"
}
```

I've tried with all regex combinations I know, but I can't seem to find a good solution for it to work.

Comment: That does seem like an issue, but have you tried writing the steps as query parameters and not random additions to your URL ?

Comment: You can try [this](https://regex101.com/r/lATsxq/1/)

Comment: @zfrisch: Well, I have to keep it that way for now. I know it might make more sense to keep it in query parameters, but even so - that's not what I'm looking for now.

Comment: @CodeManiac THANKS! It works! I forgot you can provide custom regexp for a react-router parameter.

Comment: Aaaand I take it back. @CodeManiac - as I need to do exact route it falls back to 
something like that:


"params": {
    "0": "slug-of-title-",
    "id": "106/Steps",
    "view": "123,123,-2"
  }

Comment: It's using https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0 underneath, to be clear